# ocamlfind: Package `core' not found

Tags: ocaml

I've installed `core` using `opam`, added opam config to the bash environment,
but I can't compile a program using the core module (the module is installed):

```
$ opam install core
[NOTE] Package core is already installed (current version is 113.33.03).

$ ocamlfind ocamlopt -o progprog -linkpkg -package core test1.ml
ocamlfind: Package `core' not found
```

If I do `ocamlfind list` I can't see the package (`core`) in the list.

What could be the reason?

Comment: `eval $(opam config env)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like that the `ocamlfind` utility, that you're using comes not from opam, but from your system, thus it doesn't see the opam installed stuff. This is a common symptom of a deactivated opam. Try to activate it, so that the PATH variable will contain a path to the proper `ocamlfind`:

```
eval `opam config env`
```